# LNK1104 Error: Win32 Visual Studio solution not compiling. How to fix a linker error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, linker, visual-studio-2017

The error is giving the following:

```
Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\ann\Documents\Dev\Devr\build\Core\Common\test\network\Debug\network_test.exe'  
network_test C:\Users\ann\Documents\Dev\Devr\build\Core\Common\test\network\LINK    1
```

I have cleaned, and rebuilt the entire solution. I also changed from Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to 10.0.14393.0. I saw this in a Microsoft technical document as a possible solution. Does anyone know how to resolve this linker error?

Comment: `network_test.exe` in use. may be it running or another program hold it. this is not link error.

Comment: I restarted my computer and suddenly everything works. Any advice to figure out what was hijacking network_test.exe so this doesn't happen again? @RbMm

Comment: i can not know this. may be exe run, or you copy it to vm and it hold it, or some another tool. can be huge count of variants

Comment: @aweez -- I believe there are some issues with the Visual Studio environment holding onto EXE's, thus not allowing the link phase to complete.  I would have just restarted Visual Studio instead of rebooting the machine.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that made sense to me, but when I restarted Visual Studio I had the same issues immediately - it is resolved temporarily by restarting my computer. Could there be another issue I'm missing?

Comment: @aweez -- It probably is one of those "helper" apps that get started when a compile / link / debug is taking place in Visual Studio, and you just need to kill them via Task Manager.  One of them is probably holding onto your exe.  I know there is one that gets started that sometimes goes haywire when a build is attempted, and it needs to be killed before building again (can't remember the name -- you can google for it).